# Is there any better way to wrap a callback function into async/promise?

Tags: node.js, promise, async-await

I'm using a NPM package called "node-binance-api" it is really nice lib, however it use many regular callback() as argument in it is code.

My framework is based on Async/Await as much is possible or promisify, which cannot be used by default in this code because the callback() is the second argument from the 3.

Here is my actual solution using the stock Promise to make it useable for my Async/Await codebase.

```
  promise_get_candlestick(symbol, interval, options = null) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      binance.candlesticks(
        symbol,
        interval,
        (error, ticks) => {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          } else {
            resolve(ticks);
          }
        },
        options
      );
    });
  }
```

However I am aware that it is not the best solution for this case, is there any better way to wrap this without any 3rd party Package?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this library uses the classic callback pattern where the first argument is an error, and the second one a successful result.

There is a built-in node.js utility to do the conversion.

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
const promise_get_candlestick = promisify(
  binance.candlesticks.bind(binance)
);
```

Comment: Yes, it does work until I let them use the default parameters:

`promise_get_candlestick("BTCTUSD", "5m") // work`

`promise_get_candlestick("BTCTUSD", "5m", { limit: 500 })// TypeError: callback.call is not a function`

Comment: @regdvsgrevdafsy then your choices are to not use default parameters, or you keep your own version.

Answer (score 0):

I actually don’t see anything wrong with this. It allows you to do 
`await promise_get_candlestick(symbol, interval, options)` which I guess is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```js
const promise_get_candlestick = promisify(
  (symbol, interval, options = null, callback) =>
    binance.candlesticks(symbol, interval, callback, options)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const foo = async (symbol, interval, options) => {
  try{
    let candles = await binance.candlesticks(symbol, interval, false, options);
    candles = bar(candles);
  }
  catch(err){
    console.log(err);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.